# Amplifying Signal From Electret Microphone

Tags: amplifier, microphone, gain

My project requires me to use an electret microphone and I am having a lot of trouble getting any decent-sized signal out of it. I currently have it configured with a 100Kohm pullup resistor and a 47uF capacitor. The signal is so weak that even if I put it through an amp with 200V/V gain, I only get an output whenever I tap the microphone or blare music straight into it with my earphones. Is there a trick to using the microphone right or do I just have a crappy one? I don't know the model because my professor didn't provide it, but 54LO is printed on the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 wires or 3?
Polarity known to be correct?
What DC feed voltage?

100k sounds high.
Try 10k

Sensitivity ratings are usually wrt 1V/Pascal = 1 V/ 94 dB Sound Pressure Level.

1V/Pascal = 94 dB SPL = "loud and close"

Real world sensitivities may be 40 - 70 dB below that (!).

-60 dB ~= 1 mV/Pascal.
-40 Db ~= 10 mV/Pascal.

This may not be far off what you are seeing depending on the mic you have and what signal level you require.

So with a 200V/V amplifier and a loud signal you'd expect about 200 mV from a -60 dB sensitivity microphone with a rather loud signal.
And 2V with a -40 dB mic.

[Microphone output and gain calculator here](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-transferfactor.htm)

---

[Nicely done amplifer article here](http://vk1od.net/module/SoundCardPreamp/SoundCardPreAmp.htm) - note input DC bias resistor needed for electret.

[Many potential circuits here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=electret+amplifier&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=qVFtULX5D_GSiAf49YGoAw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=2133&bih=1153) BUT you need to have some idea of basic specs and correct connection.

[Example Hosiden mic spec sheet](http://www.es.co.th/schemetic/pdf/KUC.pdf) - all at -45 dB sensitivity.

[2 transistor electret mic preamp](http://www.workinprogress.ca/electret-microphone-amplifier/) useful.

[Another similar](http://electroschematics.com/130/electret-microphone-amplifier-circuit/) useful